# How does Quorum or any private ethereum deal with failing/unavailable nodes, Single Point of Failure (SPOF) and Settlement/Transaction finality?

Tags: transactions, quorum

How does Quorum or private ethereum deal with failing/unavailable nodes, Single Point of Failure (SPOF) and Settlement/Transaction finality?

It seems to me that only ethereum main net is truly decentralised and without a single point of failure and truly censorship free as transactions cannot be reversed.

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the consensus algorithm being used on your private chain. For Quorum related information, I would suggest reading their RAFT documentation. You could also read about QuorumChain (although this has been deprecated)

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/raft/doc.md

For private chains, and non mainnet chains you'll need to take a look at the consensus method being used. The two Proof of Authority consensus alrogithms I can think of off the top of my head are Clique, and Aura. I wouldn't go so far as to say that Quorum and private chains have single points of failure, Blockchain's, irregardless of their consensus methods are designed for high availability, no SPOFs, etc.. What they do have, generally, are centralized consensus methods.

Comment: Thanks! One question - if one of the quorum nodes fail and there was a transaction sent to it, what happens?   Does the transaction goes through?

Comment: Same manner as how ethereum does :) There really is no difference except that they extended the transaction model to have a `privateFor` section. https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Transaction-Processing